# Expose methods to test code but not to end-users?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Given:

```
public final class Dummy
{   
  /**
   * Constructor meant to be used for test code.
   * @param scope test-specific "globals"
   * @param value some user-supplied value
   */
  public Dummy(SingletonScope scope, int value)
  {
    // ...
  }

  /**
   * Constructor meant to be used by end-users.
   * @param value some user-supplied value
   */
  public Dummy(int value)
  {
    scope = someDefaultValue();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Is there a design pattern that will allow me to expose the first method to test classes that are scattered across multiple packages, and the second method to end-users?

I don't want to expose the first constructor to end-users because it clutters the API specification and I don't want it to form a de-facto standard (similar to `sun.misc.Unsafe`). The solution cannot use dependency injection or reflection.

Comment: Sounds like a code smell. Your type's implementation should not be affected by testing aspects. What would you be passing to the object being tested that wouldn't be relevant to the object in production, forcing you to do this?

Comment: i would create DummyTest extends Dummy, and move the 1st constructor to DummyTest class

Comment: @VinceEmigh System properties or environment variables. [My library](https://bitbucket.org/cowwoc/requirements/) has nothing to do with ANSI color sequences, but it uses them under the hood if they are available. ANSI detection relies on system properties and environment variables. I don't believe it makes sense to expose this information at an API level (it is an implementation detail), but I need to be able to test how my library reacts to different ANSI capabilities.

Comment: @Jerry06 Updated the question (the class was meant to be final). Your solution exposes a different problem. The class in question is not meant to be extended by end-users. If I make it non-final, I run into the problem of users trying to extend it when they shouldn't.

Comment: You could use a [mocking framework](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/TestNG_usage) to use your own `Map` and `Properties` values for `System.getProperties()` and `System.getenv()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They said it couldn't be done, but here is a solution that actually worked for me:

- Rename `Dummy` to `AbstractDummy`.
- Change its accessibility from `public` to `package-protected`.
- Create new classes called `Dummy` in both the `main` and `test` codebases that extends `AbstractDummy`.
- Now for the punchline: `Dummy` in the main codebase only exposes constructors that the end-user should see while `Dummy` in the test codebase only exposes constructors that the automated tests should see.
- Ship the `main` codebase to end-users. Only use the `test` codebase internally (do not ship it to end-users).

Here is what the final product looks like:

```
abstract class AbstractDummy
{   
  /**
   * Constructor common to all implementations.
   * @param scope scope of "global" variables
   * @param value some user-supplied value
   */
  AbstractDummy(SingletonScope scope, int value)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

In "main" codebase:

```
public final class Dummy extends AbstractDummy
{   
  /**
   * Constructor meant to be used by end-users.
   * @param value some user-supplied value
   */
  public Dummy(int value)
  {
    super(MainSingletonScope.INSTANCE, value);
  }
}
```

In "test" codebase:

```
public final class Dummy extends AbstractDummy
{   
  /**
   * Constructor meant to be used for test code.
   * @param scope test-specific "globals"
   * @param value some user-supplied value
   */
  public Dummy(SingletonScope scope, int value)
  {
    super(scope, value);
  }
}
```

Comment: No one said it couldn't be done. There's actually an answer "*You can rely on package-private modifier which allows to define internal objects/processings in a API*". Everyone else was saying the form of testing you chose (putting test-only code in your production code) was frowned upon, and the clutter you are creating isn't needed. You aren't shipping the `Dummy` test, but you are shipping `AbstractDummy`, and this goes for any other test-only production code you may write for other classes.

Comment: @VinceEmigh The only test-specific change is reading the configuration from `SingletonScope` instead of system properties. This thin abstraction layer (under 30 lines of code) allows tests to run in isolation of each other. Aside from this tiny abstraction, the code behaves identically whether it is running in production or in test. I prefer such abstractions over "magic" (dynamic proxies and bytecode rewriting) used by test frameworks, any day of the week. I don't feel this harms production code either (`SingletonScope` provides some caching guarantees that system properties cannot).

Comment: in posted code the both dummy classes cannot compile.  The super constructor expects two params. Btw you do the same thing what i proposed you : using the package-private modifier. You use the modifier on the class but you have exactly the same drawback since anyone using the same package can create it own implementation of dummy. You have the advantage of not providing the tester method in the class in production  but you have the drawback of allowing full extension of the base class in production. Maybe in your case this is less problematic.

Comment: @davidxxx Good catch on the compilation error. I'm not concerned about package-private because I can use [seal the package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html) to prevent users from subclassing in production.

Comment: Easy to catch but harder to make a perfect answer :) You learn me something. I didn't know this option. Great :)  and it would be the same thing for a class which is defined outside of the jar but in the sealed package I suppose. So the package-private method could also do the job.

Answer (score 0):

> The solution cannot use dependency injection or reflection.

If you can't use reflection you can only access members that are accessible.

**private modifier**

Your test class is a different class then your production class and also not a inner class of your production class. So it can't access private members. (inner classes can only access private members of the outer class because the compiler creates synthetic access methods with package-private scope)

So lets try the next modifier.

**package-private**

You can put the test class in the same package as your production class. Then you can access package-private members. But this also means that all other production code in the same package can access them.

Thus package-private scope is already too board for you.

But if you can't use reflection you can't make private members accessible. So private members are also not suitable for you. Finally there are no access modifiers left in java.

Comment: "*So let's try the next modifier... Finally, there are no more modifiers left*" - This kind of thought process is pretty claustrophobic. His problem is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and it seems you fell victim to it. His issue has nothing to do with Java's lack of a suitable modifier, rather than he's not asking the right question for the situation he wants to overcome. Although this answer is technically right, you probably could've gotten some votes (and accepted answer) by focusing on the *real* issue

Comment: @VinceEmigh I respectfully disagree :) I explicitly stated that I am not willing to use reflection, so your answer doesn't actually solve my problem. I've been bitten one too many times by frameworks that use reflection to inject code that I can't easily debug at runtime.

Comment: @Gili You said in your comments you want to mock values for env vars and sys props, right? If so, that is the situation you want to overcome. Your solution was to create a test-only constructor and hide it, resulting in the "hide member from end-user" problem, which dragged reflection into this. I'm saying modifiers have nothing to do with your goal (mocking the enviornment) and that this question is about a problem to your solution, and this answer targets that, when really it's all irrelevant. It's a common XY problem, and rather than dig into your *real* problem, they answered the XY.

Comment: @Gili Not to mention, if you're having troubles with frameworks, you should choose better ones. They allow us to avoid reinventing the wheel, and popular frameworks are used everywhere in enterprise testing. Hell, even enterprise applications use introspection (reflection) to wire components. Popular frameworks, especially testing frameworks, are themselves tested (on different machines if needed) many times by many people. If a framework you are using doesn't work, it's not being tested how it should be.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

Using a mocking framework such as [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/TestNG_usage), mock the environment.

---

## Do not shove test-only implementations in your production code

Not only does it needlessly increase the size of the binary you'll be distributing, but as you have learned, this can easily clutter the type's interface.

Even if it's not the public interface you're polluting, it could cause confusion within the team, so it's best to avoid putting test-only code with your production code. Testing code should exist only where it belongs: in a test.

## Why would you need to do this in the first place?

You mentioned in the comments that this is your way of being able to mock the software's environment. The problem with mocking `sysenv()` and `System.getProperty(String)` is that they're static methods. This means you cannot override such methods to mock their returned values.

It seems your solution was to access these values through a `SingletonScope` interface, which is kind of the right idea (since you could simply mock `SingletonScope`). The problem is that `SingletonScope` only exists for testing purposes: you only depend on it so you can mock values for testing.

## The Solution

You need to mock the environment before you initiate your test. Using PowerMock, you could set the return value of a static method to a specific value for the duration of the test.

It would look something like:

```
Map<String, String> mockedEnviornmentValues = ...;
when(System.sysenv()).thenReturn(mockedEnviornmentValues);

Properties mockedSystemProperties = ...;
when(System.getProperties()).thenReturn(mockedSystemProperties);
```

Answer (score -1):

With `final class` and restriction as reflection usage, I can propose you
other alternatives but these are always tricky solutions.
I don't see any simple design pattern which could solve your problem. We are limited by Java language specification.

You can rely on `package-private` modifier which allows to
define internal objects/processings in a API and to ease unit tests of an API.

So you could :

- declare the method  without modifier (so package-private). 
  In this way, it should not be accessible if they use a different package.
- create your test classes in the same package but in a test folder to make  visible the package-private method.

You could have smart clients of your lib which could cheat by using the same package level (it should be rare). I think you should not care about it while the application since they are intentional tricky actions and not a classic API use.

I see another solution which could give a perfect API but is much more tricky : when you package your API, before compiling your class, run a task which removes the undesirable method of the code source.

 If it is a single method, it should not be very complicated but if it is several methods, it may become awkward to do and to maintain.

Comment: I've downvoted this because it's incredibly bad advice

Comment: Thank you for precising it :) I agree with there are better solutions since I indicated that these are tricky solutions according to its constraints.

Answer (score -1):

Your question title mentions testing, but the question itself doesn't. I'm going to assume that you're doing this for testing purposes.

Generally speaking it is a very bad idea to write production code specifically for testing. All production code should have a reason to be there. All code delivered into production should be executed in production at some time, otherwise it shouldn't be there. Having it there costs money and time to maintain and potentially poses a security risk.

You should start be unit-testing your code as if you were an end-user, not a privileged user who understands the implementation details of the class under test -- this is often referred to as black-box testing. The aim here is to make it easier for you to change the implementation details of the unit under test without having to change the test. Often this is done by writing the test first. All collaborators to the unit under test should be mocked or stubbed and you should investigate Mockito for this.

Finally, you say that solutions can't use DI or reflection. This constraint is quite odd and goes against best practices. You are strongly encouraged to change this.

Comment: "Generally speaking it is a very bad idea to write production code specifically for testing. "

Yes but it is a general case ?
For some concerns, the client API is sometimes not enough to valid a processing or users/developers want to debug some special cases not easily reproductible without cheating. In this case in production, you may have of debug mode for **testing**. 
So, I disagree.

Comment: Testing software as if you were an end user is *black box* testing, not white box. Black box is an analogy that represents the inability to see what is going on inside (hence, the box is black), focusing strictly on input and output. White/clear box is the opposite.

Comment: @davidxxx Your production code shouldn't be littered with debug code either, for the same reason one should not include testing implementations: **it serves no use in production**. On top of that, it's a [cross-cutting concern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern), and should be handled from an [outside perspective](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) (in the case of debugging, just use a debugger).

Comment: black and white -- 3am with the flu it all looks the same to me. thanks for letting me know.